# Program to bake cookies for Xmas, classes not working properly

Tags: java, class, methods

i am tryint to make a program, in which i enter the name and quantity of the ingredients, and the temperature of the oven. The program should mix them together and tell me if it was possible to bake them or not.

Class Zutat is the class for the ingredients, with name and quantity.
Class Teig is the one used to mix all ingredients making a dough. It says for each ingredient the name and quantity that was used for making the dough, and it says at the end something like "Dough created".
Class Ofen is the one for the oven. It should cook the dough at a temperature X.
Class Weihnachtsbaeckerei is the one used to put it all together. First add the ingredients, then make the dough and bake them at a temperature. If the temperature is lower than 200, it shows on screen "Cookies are great", otherwise "You burned them".

I am new to programming with classes and methods and am kind of stucked on the class Weihnachtsbaeckerei. Can anyone help me to solve it whithout changing the other classes too much?

Thank you in advance!

```
 public class aufgabe12 {

public class Zutat{
    public String Namen;
    public int Menge;
} 

public class Teig{
    public boolean geknetet;
    public void zutatHinzufugen(String Zutat){ 
        System.out.println("Zutat hinzugefuegf: " + Zutat.Namen + " (" + Zutat.Menge + "g)");
    }
    public void kneten(){
        geknetet = true;
        System.out.println("Teig geknetet");
    }
}

public class Ofen{
    public boolean backen(String Teig, int Temperatur){
        if(Temperatur<200){
            return(true);
        } else {
            return(false);
        }
    }
    public void kneten(){}
}

public void main(String[] args){
    public class Weihnachtsbaeckerei{
        Zutat zutat1 = new Zutat();
        Zutat zutat2 = new Zutat();
        Zutat zutat3 = new Zutat();
        zutat1.Namen = "Mehl";
        zutat1.Menge = 200;
        zutat2.Namen = "Zucker";
        zutat2.Menge = 100;
        zutat3.Namen = "Eier";
        zutat3.Menge = 150;
        zutatHinzufugen(zutat1);
        zutatHinzufugen(zutat2);
        zutatHinzufugen(zutat3);
        kneten();
        ofen(zutat1, 180);
        ofen(zutat2, 180);
        ofen(zutat3, 180);
        if(ofen==true){
            System.out.println("Hmmmm lecker");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Leider schief gegangen");
        }
    }
}
```

The lines with errors are:

```
System.out.println("Zutat hinzugefuegf: " + Zutat.Namen + " (" + Zutat.Menge + "g)");
zutat1.Namen = "Mehl";
zutat1.Menge = 200;
zutat2.Namen = "Zucker";
zutat2.Menge = 100;
zutat3.Namen = "Eier";
zutat3.Menge = 150;
zutatHinzufugen(zutat1);
zutatHinzufugen(zutat2);
zutatHinzufugen(zutat3);
```

Comment: what do you mean "stuck"? do you get an error? wrong output? what's the problem?

Comment: for starters, you can't write a class inside a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merry Christmas. Please consider the changes I made to your code.

First off - your Teig needs to accept a Zutat, not a String:

```
        // Add a Zutat, not a String
        public void zutatHinzufugen(Zutat dazu) {
            System.out.println("Zutat hinzugefuegf: " + dazu.Namen + " (" + dazu.Menge + "g)");
        }
```

Then, you will want to bake the whole Teig, not the single Zutaten:

```
    public class Ofen {
        // You bake the Teig, not the Zutat
        public boolean backen(Teig teig, int Temperatur) {
            if (Temperatur < 200) {
                return (true);
            } else {
                return (false);
            }
        }

    }
```

You might want to think about throwing an Exception if the Teig is not gerührt.

Last, in your main create a Teig, create an Ofen and put if all together:

```
public void main(String[] args) {

        Teig teig = new Teig();

        Zutat zutat1 = new Zutat();
        Zutat zutat2 = new Zutat();
        Zutat zutat3 = new Zutat();
        zutat1.Namen = "Mehl";
        zutat1.Menge = 200;
        zutat2.Namen = "Zucker";
        zutat2.Menge = 100;
        zutat3.Namen = "Eier";
        zutat3.Menge = 150;

        teig.zutatHinzufugen(zutat1);
        teig.zutatHinzufugen(zutat2);
        teig.zutatHinzufugen(zutat3);
        teig.kneten();

        //You need an ofen
        Ofen ofen = new Ofen();

        //You bake only once
        if (ofen.backen(teig, 180)) {
            System.out.println("Hmmmm lecker");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Leider schief gegangen");
        }
    }
```

Here's the completed code:

```
public class WeihnachtsbaeckereiTest {

    public class Zutat {
        public String Namen;
        public int Menge;
    }

    public class Teig {

        public boolean geknetet;

        // Add a Zutat, not a String
        public void zutatHinzufugen(Zutat dazu) {
            System.out.println("Zutat hinzugefuegf: " + dazu.Namen + " (" + dazu.Menge + "g)");
        }

        public void kneten() {
            geknetet = true;
            System.out.println("Teig geknetet");
        }
    }

    public class Ofen {
        // You bake the Teig, not the Zutat
        public boolean backen(Teig teig, int Temperatur) {
            if (Temperatur < 200) {
                return (true);
            } else {
                return (false);
            }
        }

    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        Teig teig = new Teig();
        Zutat zutat1 = new Zutat();
        Zutat zutat2 = new Zutat();
        Zutat zutat3 = new Zutat();
        zutat1.Namen = "Mehl";
        zutat1.Menge = 200;
        zutat2.Namen = "Zucker";
        zutat2.Menge = 100;
        zutat3.Namen = "Eier";
        zutat3.Menge = 150;

        teig.zutatHinzufugen(zutat1);
        teig.zutatHinzufugen(zutat2);
        teig.zutatHinzufugen(zutat3);
        teig.kneten();

        //You need an ofen
        Ofen ofen = new Ofen();

        //You bake only once
        if (ofen.backen(teig, 180)) {
            System.out.println("Hmmmm lecker");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Leider schief gegangen");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jan, i corrected it all and got no warnings, but still i cant run the programm. First i get the error Error: Main method is not static in class WeihnachtsbaeckereiTest, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args) and if i change it to static i get the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 No enclosing instance of type WeihnachtsbaeckereiTest is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type WeihnachtsbaeckereiTest (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Weihnachtsbaeck.. l36

Comment: Then you might want to accept the answer :-) Fröhliches Keksebacken.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would suggest a different approach. Of course it is possible to put all the classes inside the your class aufgabe12 (which is kind of misspelled, since Java classes should start with an uppercase letter according to code conventions, so better use Aufgabe12).

If you want to create an object oriented program, I would advise you to split those classes up a bit and create single files for each class. Declare the variables as private and use getters and setters. it would look like this for example:

```
public class Zutat{
  private String namen;
  private int menge;
  //talking about conventions, don't use upper case letters for variables unless they are constants.


public String getNamen(){
  return this.namen;
}

public void setNamen(String namen){
    this.namen = namen;
}

//do the same thing with the variable "menge".

//it's also a good idea to create a constructor for that class that creates an instance of Zutat for you. That would look as follows:

public Zutat(String namen, int menge){
    this.namen = namen;
    this.menge = menge;
}

}
```

From the main method you'd create the instance like this.

```
public void static main(String[] args){
Zutat z1 = new Zutat("Mehl", 200);
}
```

As already pointed out you can't specify a class inside a method. this is what's causing the compilation errors.

Given the semantics I guess you should start by replacing aufgabe12 with Weihnachtsbäckerei. (don't use 'ä' tho) This should be the class that wraps around the main method.

By putting it all together you'd get the following:

```
public class Weihnachtsbaeckerei{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Teig teig = new Teig();
    Zutat zutat1 = new Zutat("Mehl", 200);
    Zutat zutat2 = new Zutat("Zucker", 100);
    Zutat zutat3 = new Zutat("Eier", 150);

    teig.zutatHinzufugen(zutat1);
    teig.zutatHinzufugen(zutat2);
    teig.zutatHinzufugen(zutat3);
    teig.kneten();

    Ofen ofen = new Ofen();

    if (ofen.backen(teig, 180)) {
        System.out.println("Hmmmm lecker");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Leider schief gegangen");
    }
}
}
```

Zutat.java

```
public class Zutat{

private String namen;
private int menge;

public Zutat(String namen, int menge){
    this.namen = namen;
    this.menge = menge;
}

public String getNamen(){
    return this.namen;
}

public int getMenge(){
    return this.menge;
}

}
```

Teig.java

```
public class Teig{
private boolean geknetet;

public void zutatHinzufugen(Zutat zutat){ 
    System.out.println("Zutat hinzugefuegf: " + zutat.getNamen() + " (" + zutat.getMenge() + "g)");
}

public void kneten(){
    this.geknetet = true;
    System.out.println("Teig geknetet");
}
}
```

Ofen.java

```
public class Ofen{
public boolean backen(Teig teig, int temperature){
    if(temperature < 200){
        return(true);
    } else {
        return(false);
    }
}
//Der Ofen knetet nicht...and it's never called. Therefore delete this method.
public void kneten(){}
}
```

I hope this helps... since you're assignment is now already solved twice. I don't know if it was part of the task to split up your code into different classes and files, but this is basically what makes Java as efficient as it is, so try to keep that in mind. If you have any questions don't hesitate. Merry Christmas!